# How to make long blocks of text display one screen at a time?

Tags: ruby

Like how the man pages prompt your for `--more--` - is there a way to do this in Ruby?

Maybe something with "pretty_print" or "awesome_print"? Or would it involve getting information about the terminal window size, a la: https://gist.github.com/acook/4190037

```
# via http://www.megasolutions.net/ruby/Getting-the-size-of-the-terminal-in-a-portable-way-26006.aspx
TIOCGWINSZ = 0x40087468 

def get_winsize
  str = [0, 0, 0, 0].pack('SSSS') 
  if STDIN.ioctl(TIOCGWINSZ, str) >= 0 
    rows, cols, xpixels, ypixels = str.unpack("SSSS") 
    p rows, cols, xpixels, ypixels 
  else 
    puts "Unable to get window size" 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you expect something to be needed in Ruby, it’s usually already implemented [`IO#winsize`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-winsize):

```
▶ $stdin.winsize
#⇒ [ 105, 172 ]
```

---

Whether you are on *nix machine, I would go with using `more`/`less` commands to perform this task:

```
▶ text = "very long text"
▶ system <<CMD
▷ echo '#{text.gsub("'", "’")}' | less
▷ CMD
```

Comment: Yeah, Ruby seems kinda awesome like that. So, to print a big block of text such that it only displays one screensworth of text per prompt (like long man pages), the text is formatted per the current console window size using `$stdout.winsize` ? When I `require "io/console"` I get "bad file descriptor" from `$stdin.winsize` in the irb, but stdout displays my current size.

Comment: Please see an update. If I understood the question properly, using internal OS commands should suffice. If not, one should implement the pagination himself.

Comment: excellent word: pagination. Sometimes just correctly describing the idea helps a lot!

Comment: That’s why we all have a yellow rubber duck on the table to discuss ideas with :)

Comment: Heh. ::quack:: :)

Comment: ah, yes... in this instance, I can just invoke my text program with `ruby script.rb | more` nicely. . . Still speaking with my duck to see what type of programming I can muster to make long text things quack out a screen at a time.

Comment: Yes, you could if and only there is only one long text sheet to be paginated. But as you have to display smth., then ask user for an input and then display anything again, just piping to `more` won’t work.

Comment: Noted that when I tried piping to `more` a similarly "bloggy" script which also takes $ARGV...  I think there's a way to accommodate any relative window size and pagination, but it'll take a little more constructing. Your comments have been very helpful - thank you!